# how can i make input file like this with css and bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: input file]

I want to create an input type file in bootstrap but the browse icon is always on the left

```
                    <div class="col-sm-4 p-5">
                    <label class=" text-white">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control text-white " style="background-color:#319b9e"
                        placeholder="Enter full name" />
                    <span class="form-text text-muted"></span>
                </div>
```

this is my code

output

[image]

Comment: Show us your code in order to help you.

Comment: oke wait hol onnn

Comment: hmm yeah like that bro .. but the (browser) keep on left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <label for="formFileLg" class="form-label">Large file input example</label>
  <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="formFileLg" type="file" style="
    direction: rtl;
">
</div>
```